# Show that if X has a density f such that f’ exists and is integrable?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Show that if $X$ has a density $f$ such that $f'$ exists and is integrable, then its characteristic function has the property :   $\phi(t)=ο(t^{-1} )$   as  $t\to \infty$.

Hint: If $X$ has a density then its characteristic function has the property:  $\lim_{t\to \infty}⁡\phi(t)=0$.
You may use this result.

how can start with this hint to prove that any help

Comment: what is the relation between the characteristic function of $f$ and the characteristic function of $f'$?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- expressing $\phi$ by an integral involving $f'$, we obtain that 
  $$t\cdot |\phi(t)|\leqslant \left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)e^{itx}\mathrm dx\right|;$$
- the Fourier transform of an integrable function vanishes at infinity. To see this, approximate the function by characteristic functions of finite unions of intervals.